# Split datetimerange into start/end weeks

Tags: sql-server-2012

I am trying to split the datetimerange column in my data to group by start -end of the week. I got it working with this query, but the problem is when date in my data is not the start of the week, I want the date from my data and not the startData

But when I added the ActualStartDate select, this gives me days in the same week as multiple rows, which is not what I want.

My data has these dates in it.

```
11/12/2014
11/13/2014
11/14/2014
11/15/2014
11/18/2014
11/21/2014
11/22/2014
```

My query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
DATEPART(ww, Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime] ,101)) AS Week,
CONVERT(varchar, [initiateDateTime],101) as ActualStartDate,
--CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dd, -(DATEPART(dw, Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime],101))-1), Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime],101)),101) AS StartDateWeek,
CONVERT(varchar, DATEADD(dd, 6-(DATEPART(dw, Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime],101))-1), Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime],101)),101)  AS EndDateWeek
FROM [LogData].[dbo].[InitLogs]
WHERE [initiateDateTime] BETWEEN '11/12/2014' AND '01/08/2015'  
GROUP BY DATEPART(ww, Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime] ,101)),CONVERT(varchar, [initiateDateTime],101)
ORDER BY DATEPART(ww, Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime] ,101))
```

This outputs:

```
46  11/12/2014  11/15/2014
46  11/13/2014  11/15/2014
46  11/14/2014  11/15/2014
46  11/15/2014  11/15/2014
47  11/18/2014  11/22/2014
47  11/21/2014  11/22/2014
47  11/22/2014  11/22/2014
```

However, AS 11/13 and 11/14 are in the same week as 46, I want the query to return only one row

```
46  11/12/2014  11/15/2014
47  11/18/2014  11/22/2014
```

Thanks for looking.

Update:
Solved it with a nested sql like this for the actualdate

```
(SELECT 
    Top 1 (Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime] ,101)) 
    FROM [LogData].[dbo].[InitLogs] 
    WHERE 
    [initiateDateTime] BETWEEN '11/1/2014' AND '01/08/2015'
    AND 
    DATEPART(wk, Convert(varchar, [initiateDateTime] ,101)) = DATEPART(wk, Convert(varchar, FL.initiateDateTime,101))
    ) As StartDate,
```